# Making AHK script in Notepad ++

Tags: autohotkey

Im trying to make an ahk script to try and simplify a one time use script. Pretty much im running over 1000 commands in a game one after one another .Currently I have something like this. I have all the commands in a single text file just not with any ahk coding.

```
.waypointadd 1 100234 40 -469
.waypointadd 2 99549 34 5
.waypointadd 3 100615 37 -160
.waypointadd 4 100817 27 -457
.waypointadd 5 100503.5 10.5 -647.5
.waypointadd 6 100494.5 10.5 -625.5
```

This goes on for a while. Im new to using expressions and such and am pretty much trying to make it to press enter, type the command, then press enter, then go to the next one. I obviously cant do this manually. I have tried using some basic replace expressions and stuff but not really sure how to do this.

In the end i would want it to look like this

```
send {enter}
send (command 1)
send {enter}
send {enter}
send (command 2)
send {enter}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could bind it to a key like....

```
1::
loop, 1 {
  send {enter}
  send (command 1)
  send {enter}
  send {enter}
  send (command 2)
  send {enter}
}
```

or make a function when you a press a key. lmk if this helps or not

```
doSomething() {
  send {enter}
  send (command 1)
  send {enter}
  send {enter}
  send (command 2)
  send {enter}
}

1::
doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the commands in your clipboard (CTRL+C them) and then loop through all of them:

```
Loop, Parse, Commands, `n, `r ;split by linefeed, ignore carriage return
{
    SendInput, % A_LoopField "{Enter 2}"
    Sleep, 1000 ;however long you need
}
```

Loads of ways to get the commands *into* your script, I just went with loading them from your clipboard, should be pretty easy convenient to just copy the block of commands you want and then starting the script.
Then there's a [parsing loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm).
And then [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) is used to send the current command follow by two presses of `Enter`.
Alternatively, if your game supports pasting from clipboard, it would be nice to just load your clipboard with whatever you want to send, and then sending a CTRL+V.

If the code with SendInput is going too fast, you can try switching over to normal `Send` and maybe even using [`SetKeyDelay`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) to add even more delay between the keypresses.